# Functional inequality $f'(x)^3-f'(x)^2-9f'(x)+9\leq0$

Tags: calculus

f(x) meets the following conditions.

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&f'(x) \text{ is continuous for all }x\\
&f'(x)^3-f'(x)^2-9f'(x)+9\leq0\\
&f(0)=0\\
&f(2016)=4102
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Find maximum and minimum of
$$\int_{1}^{5}f(x)dx$$
and also values of $f(x)$ at the minimum and the maximum of the above expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inequality of the polynomial of the derivative function can be written as follows: $$(f'(x) - 1)(f'(x) - 3)(f'(x) + 3) \le 0$$ 
This can happen only if $f'(x) \le -3$ or $1 \le f'(x) \le 3$ for all $x \epsilon R$

which implies that $f(x) \le -3x + c$ or $x + c \le f(x) \le 3x + c$

Now I'll focus on the second condition since this seems to be the only condition which can give both the maximum and minimum bounds

see that $f(0) = 0$ implies that $c \le 0 \le c$ which implies that $c = 0$

Thus $x \le f(x) \le 3x$ and hence $\int_1^5 xdx \le \int_1^5 f(x)dx \le \int_1^5 3x dx$ , I.e. the upper and lower bounds are $36$ and $12$ respectively.